# pymongo sort returning record that doesn't have the sorting key

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting, pymongo

I am sorting through a collection on it's date column to find the minimum date in that collection. However, it returns me a record where the date key is missing. Below is the snippet. Is this a bug?

```
date_records = usercollection.find({'customer_id':'abc'}).sort('join_date',1).limit(1)
for record in date_records:
    print record # prints a record that doesn't have the join_date key
    print record['join_date']
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("94dbe4c6ea890e28113d7664"), "region" : "Virginia", "country_code" : "US", "customer_id" : "abc"}

KeyError: u'join_date'
```

Comment: This is not a bug. Quick question: do you want to sort only the records which contain `join_date` field?

Comment: Yes, I want to retrieve the earliest date from all records that have the join_date field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug and how [`sort` in MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) is supposed to work:

> The comparison treats a non-existent field as it would an empty BSON
>   Object. As such, a sort on the a field in documents { } and { a: null
>   } would treat the documents as equivalent in sort order.

And, since you've noted:

> I want to retrieve the earliest date from all **records that have the
>   join_date field**

check for `join_date` to exist using [`$exists`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/):

```
usercollection.find({
    'customer_id': 'abc',
    'join_date': {'$exists': True}
}).sort('join_date', 1)
```